# Перевод из двоичной системы счисления в десятичную

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, помогите, пожалуйста, исправить скрипт перевода из двоичной системы счисления в десятичную

```
<?php

$bin = 101; // Число которое нужно перевести
function myBin2Dec($bin) {
  $base = 10;

  $n = 1;
  $dec = 0;
  $bin = (string)$bin;
  echo "=======\n<br>bin = $number; base = $base\n</br>=======</br>";
  for ($i = strlen($bin)-1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
    if ($bin{$i}=="1"); 
    $dec = $dec + $n;
    $n = $n * 2;
    echo "bin = $bin; n = $n; dec = $dec\n</br>";        
  }      
  return $dec;
}

$result = myBin2Dec($bin);
echo "result = ".$result."\n</br>;

?>
```

Comment: Уточните, в чем проблема.

Comment: открываю скрипт, а он выводит либо ошибку, либо пустой экран

Comment: Готовые функции Вам не подходят?

Comment: @andrey26rus, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ на *данный* вопрос, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
$bin = "101";
function myBin2Dec($bin) {
    for ($base = 10, $n = 1, $dec = 0, $i = strlen((string)$bin)-1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
        if ((int)$bin{$i} == 1) 
            $dec +=$n; 
        $n *=  2;  
    }
    echo "=======\n<br>bin = ".$bin."; base = ".$base."\n</br>=======</br>";
  return $dec;
}
$result = myBin2Dec($bin);
echo "result = ".$result."\n</br>";
?>
```

**Исправил код! Теперь полноценно работает!**

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь, тоже все работает уже

Comment: Если вопрос решен, выберите правильный ответ.

Comment: еще по этому скрипту появился вопрос, я проверил его, поставил, чтоб можно было вводить с клавиатуры двоичное число. Для пробы пишу 101, должно 5 быть, а получается 7. Почему?

Comment: Исправил =)

Comment: спасибо большое, а что там не так было?

Comment: 0 считало как 1

Comment: @Node_pro - нет, он, все еще, открыт...

Comment: был закрыт, когда писал.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "result = ".$result."\n</br>**"**;
```

Кавычку забыли.

Двоичные числа хотя бы в строку обернули: `$bin = '1001010';`

Answer (score 1):

```
> $bin = "101"; 
> function myBin2Dec($bin) { 
>     for ($base = 10, $n = 1, $dec = 0, $i = strlen((string)$bin)-1; $i >= 0;
> $i--) { 
>         if ((int)$bin{$i} == 1)  
>             $dec +=$n;  
>         $n *=  2;   
>     } 
>     echo "=======\n<br>bin = ".$bin."; base = ".$base."\n</br>=======</br>"; 
> return $dec;  }
```

Я вижу тут много лишнего. Делаем так:

```
$bin = "101";
function myBin2Dec($bin) {
    $n = strlen((string)$bin);
    for ($dec = 0, $i = 0; $i < n; $i++) {
        $dec = 2 * $dec + (int)$bin{$i};
    }
    echo "=======\n<br>bin = ".$bin."; base = 10\n</br>=======</br>";
  return $dec;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь)))

Comment: как закрыть теперь этот вопрос, задача решена

Answer (score 0):

Если кто-то будет искать аналогичные функции, я приведу парочку.

Стандартная встроенная функция: [bindec()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.bindec.php)

И минифицированная:

```
function bin2dec($b){for($i=0,$n=0,$l=strlen($b);$i<$l;$i++){$n+=(substr($b,$l-1-$i,1)=='1'?pow(2,$i):0);}return $n;}
```